# Fetching Core Data several times

Tags: swift, core-data

I am building a chat app with core data and there is `ViewController` with list of chats. I am trying to update this list everytime before view appears:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        chatlist.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }

        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "MessagesList")
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

        do {
            self.chatlist = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

But it is calling only once, when I go to another `ViewController` and return back to this one, data is not updating, fetch query is not working for the second time. How to fetch data from Core Data everytime when VC appears or even better how to update data in background inside the VC?

Comment: You have to call reloadData after fetching your data, not before it. put it inside your do..catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First open table reloads automatically but not the second appear so try 
to reload the table after you set the array like

```
 self.chatlist = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
 tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: no, sir, `viewWillAppear` is calling every time, `chatlist.removeAll()` works properly, but fetch query does not work for second time, I see only empty `tableView`